# deployment Python Django applications to AWS Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How long does it take to deploy Python Django applications to AWS-Beanstalk (for a simple social-platform) normally? Developers are giving me estimations 90 to 100 hours of work. It feels like a bit rip off.

Are there responsible, experienced professionals here set up the deployment?

Comment: What are you asking? Deployment takes a second. Do you actually have an application ready to deploy?

Comment: Yes, I have application and codes ready on a private Gitlab account. It still needs some improvements however I need  my platform run as soon as possible. My developer was not able to deploy, integrate and run the platform on AWS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time I deployed a Django app to aws eb it took me about ten to twelve hours of work.
AWS eb is not the easiest to work with because of the lack of good documentation.
Still if you understand what's going on it's not that bad.

Comment: Are you experienced on AWS beanstalk deployment? The reason I am asking is that I´m looking for someone.

Comment: Just saw your comment now, I probably have the experience you need, you can contact me at aviadm32@gmail.com for more explanations if you'd like.